# Python regex match space but remove from grouping

Tags: python, xml, regex

Given the following lines of XML:-

```
<tmpr>10.85</tmpr><sensor>01</sensor><ch1><watts>1000</watts></ch1>

<tmpr>-1.85</tmpr><sensor>01</sensor><ch1><watts>1000</watts></ch1>
```

I can use the following Python Regular Expression to match three capturing groups:-

```
<tmpr>*([\-\d.]+)</tmpr>.*<sensor>(\d+)</sensor>.*<ch1><watts>0*(\d+)</watts></ch1>
```

The problem is, when the temperature drops below 10.00 the XML introduces a leading space:-

```
<tmpr> 9.85</tmpr><sensor>01</sensor><ch1><watts>1000</watts></ch1>
```

How could I modify the Regular Expression to capture the temperature but ignore the leading space ?

Comment: Why don't you use regular XML parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, such regex will work:

```
<tmpr>\s*([\-\d.]+)</tmpr>.*<sensor>(\d+)</sensor>.*<ch1><watts>0*(\d+)</watts></ch1>\n
```